# How can I insert commas in 1 word that I have tailed

Tags: linux, tail

I have a log tailed with the following output:

```
$ tail -n1 /home/shares/number-10.log
123456
```

I want the output to be: `12,34,56`

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -n1 /home/shares/number-10.log | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{2})/\1,/g;s/,[[:space:]]?+$//'
```

Enable sed regular expression interpretation with -r or -E and then substitute all cases of a digit occurring two times with the two digits followed by a comma. Then in the second statement, remove the comma at the end.

Amended answer as requested:

```
tail -n1 /home/shares/number-10.log | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{2})/\1|/g;s/|[[:space:]]?+$//'
```

Does the same as the first example but uses "|" instead of ","

Comment: thank you for the quick reply,

I noticed that I don't like (,) because it's not clear.

I changed it to (|) and now I see that the output is almost correct.


12|34|56|

I would like to have the last stroke removed, what do I have to change?

Comment: No worries. I have amended the answer

Comment: Okay, but the problem is the output is "12 | 34 | 56 |" but i want/need "12 | 34 | 56"

Comment: s/|$// should remove the last |. If there is some other text coming from the tail command, can you please post it.

Comment: I added amended to take account of any spaces at the end of the number returned by tail

Comment: Hello, idk why but it dosn't work.  tail -n1 /home/shares/number-10.log | grep 'TRAID' --line-buffered | stdbuf -oL cut -b108-113 | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{2})/\1|/g;s/|[[:space:]]?+$//'

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use the bash variable operations:

```sh
var=`tail -n1 /home/shares/number-10.log`
echo "${var:0:2},${var:2:2},${var:4:2}"
echo "${var:0:2}|${var:2:2}|${var:4:2}"
```